# JUnitParams for each method of class

Tags: java, testing, junitparams

Is it possible to run parameterized test for each method of test class with JUnitParams and class level annotations? Something like:

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
@Parameters(method = "paramsGenerator")
public class TestMethod {

    public Integer[] paramsGenerator() {
        return new Integer[] {1, 2, 3};
    }

    @Test
    public void test1(Integer myInt) {
        ......
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(Integer myInt) {
        ......
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try before asking? This should be de default behaviour.

Comment: Yes, it should be, but it's not. I'm getting `Method test1 should have no parameters`

Comment: You have to define a constructor that takes the param and stores it in a field. the methods can then use the value from the field - not as param.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot have a class-level parameters annotation that would cover all test methods. You must declare `@Parameters(method = "paramsGenerator")` on each test method. Your use case is pretty rare - most often different test methods require different parameters (eg. you have one method for valid and one for invalid input).

Answer (score 1):

The test class should be like this:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Testcase {

    private int myInt;

    public Testcase(int myInt) {
        this.myInt = myInt;
    }

    @Parameters(name = "{0}")
    public static Collection<Integer> data() {
        Integer[] data = new Integer[] {1,2,3,4};

        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        // TODO
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

I don't know where you got `JUnitParamsRunner` from. As you can see in my example, JUnit 4 defines `Parameterized`.

Comment: The question is about [JUnitParams](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams), not JUnit `Parameterized`